# How do you send a custom attribute to the Django admin site context?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to send a custom attribute (True or False) to the Django admin website so that it can be accessed in a custom template as such:

```
{{ model.highlight_background }}
{% if model.highlight_background %}
```

Right now I have a method of doing this which feels incredibly hacky: I'm overriding the `admin.AdminSite._build_app_dict` to put `'highlight_background': model._meta.permissions,` into `model_dict` and then adding `permissions = (('highlight_background', 'Highlight Background'),)` to the Meta class of the model I want this to occur on, and then calling using `model.highlight_background.0.0` in the template.

This "works", in that I am able to do exactly what I want with this information, but it doesn't seem like the "correct" way of doing it.  What I would like to know is if there is a better way of going about doing this, preferably without overriding anything other than the admin site templates, or overriding as little as possible.

I have since started going down the rabbit hole of overriding the `django.db.models.options.Options.__init__` to add `self.highlight_background = False` and just directly utilize `highlight_background = True` in the `Meta` class, but I thought I had better ask if there is a proper way of going about this before I spend too much time hacking together my own, less than ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just hard-coding it into the custom template.

```
{% if model.object_name == 'XXXX' or model.object_name == 'YYYY' or model.object_name == 'ZZZZ' %}
```

Not pretty, but not nearly as ugly as what I was doing to avoid this, and a lot easier to edit down the road as well.  I'm not marking this as *the* answer, but it's my work-around until I or someone else finds something better.